# Client side code is not generated for XElement properties

Tags: wcf, c#-4.0, silverlight-4.0, ria

> My domain service has invoke operation method and returns a custom
>   type say 'User'. This class has many properties such as String,
>   Integer, Boolean, XElement. When I rebuild the solution to generate
>   client-side proxy, it generates code for the class User in the client
>   for all the properties, except for XElement. What is the fix for this?
>   Will RIA not generate any code for XNode or XElement types? Should
>   these elements be converted to String? Are there any fixes for this
>   error?

I'm using VS2010 SP1, .Net Framework 4, WCF RIA, Silverlight 5.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Silverlight DataContract documentation,](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kd1dc9w5%28v=VS.95%29.aspx) you can mark your classes as either opt-in using the DataContract/DataMember attributes or opt-out and rely on only serializing public scope class members. You need to show the code of the class you're having problems with to get better suggestions.